# Java generics and instanceof

Tags: java, generics, casting

Wondering how to properly do the conditional cast with Java generics.

First `castTo` method in my example seems to be the most obvious but it gives me a compile time error `A cannot be casted to T` and I understand that's because of Java type erasure feature.

I came up with the second version of `castTo` where I need to pass a class and use `isInstance()` which works but looks ugly.

Is there any better way to do it? I hate passing the class parameter every time and the second method doesn't look like a modern java 21 approach to me.

```
class A {
    int value = 1;
}

class B extends A {
    A getObject() {
        return new B();
    }
    <T extends A> T castTo(A obj) {
        // Compile error: A cannot be casted to T
        if (obj instanceof T casted) {
            return casted;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // This method works without an error
    // but requires to pass a Class
    <T extends A> T castTo(A obj, Class<T> targetType) {
        if (targetType.isInstance(obj)) {
            return targetType.cast(obj);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

FYI this is just an example to demonstrate the issue, the actual code is more complicated than what you see in `castTo` method, so the advide to use `B result = a instanceof B b? b: null;` instead of this method is good but not what I seek.

Comment: Off topic: this might be a good place to return `Optional<T>` so you can't forget the `null` check.

Comment: Just let the caller do `B result = a instanceof B b? b: null;` instead of calling another method. Your method even requires an existing `B` instance to invoke it; that’s an unnecessary complication. Especially, as making the method generic suggests that you have support for subclasses of `A` other than `B` in mind. But why should casts to `C` require dealing with class `B`?

Comment: @Holger this is just an example to demonstrate the issue, the actual code is more complicated. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Maybe there’s an elegant solution for your actual problem then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do it?

No.  You must explicitly pass the `Class` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, although you need to be careful.

```java
    public <T> T cast(Object v, T... type) {
        if (type.getClass().getComponentType().isInstance(v)) {
            return (T) v;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This works because when method is called, an empty array of type T will be created. We can get its class and component type to check for a type of T.
However, due to how generics work in Java, this will not always work: if compiler is not able to deduct the type of T, you will end up with type of `java/lang/Object` or base type of T.

Edit: As suggested in comments to the question, it is much better to use pattern matching instead. See [this](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) JEP for more info.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you @alzs. You are right that this won't always work and that's sad. I upvoted your answer but didn't set it as a main one as it has this caveat.
Also your code still contains the warning: `Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'T'` due of `return (T) v;`